# Xcode font scale (auto-shrink) not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, autoshrink

I have a label, in which is a main feature of the content. I therefore have it set to autoshrink.

The problem is that when I run it on some of the smaller devices, the text is shifted downwards horrendously based on the label box.

How do I fix this?

[image]

**Edit:** This shows the problem that the labels do not fill the container after fixing the autoshrink shifting problem

[image]

Comment: check if number of lines is 1 and you have setted properly your constraints

Comment: If number of lines meant to be 1 or 0?

Comment: 1 if you want to font scale works, well 1 or any fixed number, if is 0 the label grows in size and the font don't scale

Comment: Thanks. You have prompted me to make it work. Having 0 lines actually makes font-scale work. Thanks! If you write it as a proper answer I will rate is as right.

Comment: added as an answer

Comment: you fix the issue using numberOfLines = 0?

Comment: Yes. It not works perfectly pretty much.

Comment: Apart from that the fact that the label text does not 100% expand fully to the bounds of the container. - Any way to fix this easily?

Comment: you need to use your cell with automaticDimension I think that is the main issue

Comment: What does that mean? Any code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165370/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-d-a-uk).

Comment: You are using a UITableViewCells, in UITableView right?

Comment: Yes. What you did fixed the shifting. One problem, however, is that the labels do not fill the container. A demonstration shows this using background colours. I have put the photo in the original post.

Comment: ok, I missunderstand your issue i will update my answer

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate all you have done and are doing to help me :)

Comment: check my updated answer, if you need the label fill the container vertically you need to adjust the constraints

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is that your number of lines for those UILabels is fixed, and you need numberOfLines = 0 to allow that `UILabel` frame size grow as it needs to, using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in your Cell

Comment: This is misleading.  Setting `numberOfLines` to 0 will *prevent* autoshrink entirely.

Comment: @GrantPalmer you are right i was thinking that the OP wants to grow the cell instead of shrink the Label that's why

Comment: This answer certainly helped me. I have constraints controlling the label size, and Autoshrink set to 'Minimum Font Scale'. Curiously, setting the number of Lines to any number *other* than 1 works—0, 2, 3, whatever. As long as it's *not* 1, the font scales down to fit the label size. How odd!

Answer (score 3):

For auto shrink in Storyboard attribute inspector

**A.** Select Automatic Adjust Font [image]

**B.** Change Auto shrink to minimum font scale/size.
[image]

**NOTE:** In some case try to test with line breaking mode to get working state.